# Framework used for Scandit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios4

I want to know which framework is being used by the App [Scandit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scandit-barcode-scanner-comparison/id393740899?mt=8).Secondly, what is the best option to go for it,if I want to use bar code scanning functionality in my app.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ScannerKit** for iPhone/Android

Barcode Scanner SDK for iPhone and Android supporting both 1D (UPC and EAN) and 2D (QR and Datamatrix) barcodes. Specifically designed to work on both fixed and variable focal length cameras, our Barcode Scanning library is one of the best in the business and best of all it is FREE!

Comment: Is it free??My friend are you suggesting this link https://spur.wufoo.com/forms/barcode-scanner-sdk-iphone-3g3gs4/ ??? If yes then it is only free for development purpose not for distribution...

Answer (score 1):

Scandit uses its own SDK which is available for other developers,too: http://www.iscandit.com/dev
They support iPhone, Android and Symbian platforms.